# make discord bot stay for x time in channle then leave but stay on action

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I have a music bot and im trying to make it leave after x time but not if 24/7 mode is enabled after the queue ends this part works the problem is that when i start a new audio plays the bot leaves still after x time

```
 .on ("queueEnd", (player) => setTimeout(() => {

        // Don't leave if 24/7 mode is active
        let QueueEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("The queue has ended", this.botconfig.IconURL)
        .setColor(this.botconfig.EmbedColor)
        .setTimestamp();

          client.channels.cache.get(player.textChannel).send( { embeds: [ QueueEmbed ] } );
  
        
          if (!this.config["24/7"]) player.destroy();
      }, 30000));
```

so if 24/7 is set to false it stays for x time but i guess i need it to cancel the destroy if audio starts playing again but cant figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the code of a `setTimeout()` from running by storing the output of the `setTimeout()` function in a variable and whenever you want to cancel the timeout just call `clearTimeout()` like so:

```js
//Storing your timeout
const timeout = setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log("Hello, World!") 
}, 3000)

//Call this to clear
clearTimeout(timeout)
```